# How to use lib.* Variables the correct way in TypoScript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

this is my first submission.
I want a specific image as Background in my Typo3 Template. I want to parse the needed Image from a reference in the Page. Below Code I copied from another website and it seems correct.

```
lib.headerimage = IMAGE
lib.headerimage {
 file {
  import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
  treatIdAsReference = 1
  import.listNum = 0
}}
```

The Problem now is, I want the lib.headerimage.FILELINK to be in my following code and I can't figure out how to use lib.VARIABLES

In a later point I parse this:

```
page.headerData {

10 = TEXT
10.value = div#header { background-image: url('lib.headerimage.file.value');}
10.wrap = <style type="text/css">|</style>  
}
```

With our without $ it doesn't parse anything. I just started using typoscript 3 days ago again. My last experiences were years back.

Please , there must be an easy way to do this. :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you search a way to concat strings. Assumed the first part is correct (As I am not familiar with the IMAGE Object) you can concat the strings like this:

```
page.headerData {

    10 = COA
    10 {
        10 = TEXT
        10.value = <style type="text/css">div#header { background-image: url('

        20 < lib.headerimage

        30 = TEXT
        30.value = ');}</style> 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx ! It partially works now, but it gives me <img-wrapped Link to the image, which isn't for CSS sadly ;) Do you know how to supress this? I tried calling lib.headerimage.file which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
lib.headerImageText = COA
lib.headerImageText {
  10 = IMG_RESOURCE
  10.file.treatIdAsReference = 1
  10.file.import {
    cObject = TEXT
    cObject.value = dummy.gif
    cObject.override {
      required = 1
      data = levelmedia: -1, slide
      listNum = 0
    }
  }
}
```

AND

```
page.headerData {

  10 = COA
  10 {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = <style type="text/css">div#header { background-image: url('
    20 < lib.headerImageText
    30 = TEXT
    30.value = ');}</style> 
}
}
```

Fixed my problem ;) now the div#header has the correct background-url defined in the typo3 backend.